# Trying to change a CodeIgniter session variable before loading, only working on reload?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies, session-variables

Ok, so we were given an application written with CodeIgniter, that has support for multiple languages.

The problem we have is that the language selection was happening outside of CodeIgniter, in a Joomla website, where the application was accessible from. However, we need to detach the games from the Joomla installation and this time handle the language selection in wordpress instead. We already set a cookie for the selected language in wordpress (cookie name is lang, values either ru or en (russian and english)) and the general idea is that the user flow is like that:

VISITOR VISITS WORDPRESS WEBSITE (where a cookie is set) -> CLICKS THROUGH TO GAMES (where Codeigniter has to check the cookie and set the session variable)

So, given the above flow, a cookie is written from the wordpress side, so this cookie can be accessed by the CodeIgniter application to set the language respectively. The code that was successful in doing so is this:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE["lang"])) {
    $this->session->set_userdata('lang', 'en');
} else {
    if ($_COOKIE["lang"] == "en") $this->session->set_userdata('lang', 'en');
    if ($_COOKIE["lang"] == "ru") $this->session->set_userdata('lang', 'ru');
}
```

This works fine, however it will not show the selected language on first load, but only when we  reload. However, this code is placed at the top of the header view of the CodeIgniter application, before everything is echoed to the browser and as far as we are aware, it is the first file that is called on all of the templates.

Is there another file/way we should be doing this? We are not experts, not even newbies in CodeIgniter so not sure where to start. We tried placing this code in other views and even controllers but it either breaks or just does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating a custom controller that extends CI_Controller and put there your logic for choosing the proper language according the cookie/session.

Make a new file named MY_Controller.php inside your application/core folder

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{

    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //get the language from the cookie if its set and use it on the view
        if (!isset($_COOKIE["lang"])) 
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('lang', 'en');
        } 
        else 
        {
            if ($_COOKIE["lang"] == "en") $this->session->set_userdata('lang', 'en');
            if ($_COOKIE["lang"] == "ru") $this->session->set_userdata('lang', 'ru');
        }
    }
}
```

Then extend MY_Controller on every controller you make on your application like so.

```
class Frontpage extends MY_Controller
```

Comment: We just tried this, but the syntax is different and although i tried to adapt, it will give me a 500 internal server error. The codeigniter verions is sady 1.7.1 so instead of the code suggested in your comment, the controllers use "Game extends Controller" instead of CI_Controller and their constructor function name is the name of the class "Game" and in the constructor instead of the parent::__construct(), they have "parent :: Controller();". Not sure how this affects the example above but anything i tried is getting me a 500 server error!

Comment: 500 server error most probably is being caused by a misconfiguration on your server or a malfunctioning htaccess file. Do you use a .htaccess file on your application? Try disabling it (by renaming it) and see what you get.

Comment: No, not at all. I think it has to do with the different code style of this old codeigniter version..

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! This finally worked. We needed to put the custom controller in /application/libraries and extend Controller instead of CI_Controller, and any controllers extending this, needed to call parent:: MY_Controller(), instead of construct. All these changes needed to happen for this to work for CodeIgniter version 1.7.1, so in case someone else has this issue, this is the proper solution, just keep in mind you need these details, as documentation for old versions are scarce.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Cookie doesnot available on same page sometimes in codeigniter.

Comment: We know that the cookie is available, it will echo just fine :)